# Updating numerous web clients periodically from the server

Tags: asp.net

G'Day,

I am planning an ASP.NET 4 application. Not sure if it will be MVC3 or WebForms yet. I need to be able to perform the following:

- I have data coming into the .NET assembly on the web server via a serial link
- I want to send this same data to all "connected" web clients
- I want to PUSH the changes from the server. NOT poll the server

"Connected" you say? HTTP is a RESTful and there are no permanent connections. So I am guessing I need to open up a web socket or similar to do this? Ideally I would also like to know what page the connected client is on so that I don't send them data they wont need (assuming I have a correlation between what is being displayed and the data it concerns).

Performance and scalability are obviously issues here. I don't foresee having more than 10 simultaneous clients in the intranet I am running on. However I would like to scale it larger and potentially include Internet connected clients.

What are my options here? All suggestions and pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [WebSocket](http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/) API, if HTML5 isn't too fancy for your intranet.  (It probably is.)

There are also [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847227/real-time-chat-with-push-notification) questions covering similar ground.